# PHPExcel fast duplicate row

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have row with different styles for each cell. I need to duplicate it (copy text, style, size).

I was using following function to do it:

```
  function copyRowFull(&$ws_from, &$ws_to, $row_from, $row_to) {
    $ws_to->getRowDimension($row_to)->setRowHeight($ws_from->getRowDimension($row_from)->getRowHeight());
    $lastColumn = $ws_from->getHighestColumn();
    $rangeFrom = 'A'.$row_from.':'.$lastColumn.$row_from;
    // copy text
    $ws_to->fromArray($ws_from->rangeToArray($rangeFrom), null, 'A'.$row_to);
    // copy style
    ++$lastColumn;
    for ($c = 'A'; $c != $lastColumn; ++$c) {
      $ws_to->duplicateStyle($ws_from->getStyle($c.$row_from), $c.$row_to);
    }
  }
```

However it it VERY slow due to loop but I need it fast because many rows will be copied.

Also I have tried this for style copying:

```
$rangeTo = 'A'.$row_to.':'.$lastColumn.$row_to;
$ws_to->getStyle($rangeTo)->applyFromArray($ws_from->getStyle($rangeFrom));
```

But it doesn't work - throws error "Invalid style array passed".

Is there any faster method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After crawling in PHPExcel sources, I have figured out a lot faster way to duplicate row. It works copying only inside one workbook but it is what I needed. Posting it, maybe someone also had or will have similar problem.

```
function copyRowFull(&$ws_from, &$ws_to, $row_from, $row_to) {
  $ws_to->getRowDimension($row_to)->setRowHeight($ws_from->getRowDimension($row_from)->getRowHeight());
  $lastColumn = $ws_from->getHighestColumn();
  ++$lastColumn;
  for ($c = 'A'; $c != $lastColumn; ++$c) {
    $cell_from = $ws_from->getCell($c.$row_from);
    $cell_to = $ws_to->getCell($c.$row_to);
    $cell_to->setXfIndex($cell_from->getXfIndex()); // black magic here
    $cell_to->setValue($cell_from->getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask if where will I put this? Is it in the Worksheet.php or in the controller? and what are the arguments? 'coz I'm having an error in pass by parameter reference. Your feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: @d_unknown Place this function anywhere in your code (not in library). `$ws_from` and `$ws_to` are Worksheet objects. `$row_from `and `$row_to` are row indexes (1-based).

Comment: Add this after $cell_from = $ws_from->getCell($c.$row_from); to duplicate merged cells as well: if($cell_from->isMergeRangeValueCell())
     {
     $col = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString(PHPExcel_Cell::splitRange($cell_from->getMergeRange())[0][1])[0];
   $ws_to->mergeCells($c.$row_to.':'.$col.$row_to); //$cell->getMergeRange()
   }

Answer (score 1):

For those on PHP 5.3 or so, Somnium's answer blended with Ravean's comment and adapted for PHP 5.3:

```
    /**
 * Copies entire row with formatting and merging
 * @param $ws_from
 * @param $ws_to
 * @param $row_from
 * @param $row_to
 * @throws PHPExcel_Exception
 */
public function copyRowFull(&$ws_from, &$ws_to, $row_from, $row_to)
{
    $ws_to->getRowDimension($row_to)->setRowHeight($ws_from->getRowDimension($row_from)->getRowHeight());
    $lastColumn = $ws_from->getHighestColumn();
    ++$lastColumn;
    for ($c = 'A'; $c != $lastColumn; ++$c) {
        $cell_from = $ws_from->getCell($c . $row_from);
        if ($cell_from->isMergeRangeValueCell()) {
            $pCoordinateString = PHPExcel_Cell::splitRange($cell_from->getMergeRange());
            $coordinateFromString = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString($pCoordinateString[0][1]);
            $col = $coordinateFromString[0];
            $ws_to->mergeCells($c . $row_to . ':' . $col . $row_to);
            //$cell->getMergeRange()
        }
        $cell_to = $ws_to->getCell($c . $row_to);
        $cell_to->setXfIndex($cell_from->getXfIndex()); // black magic here
        $cell_to->setValue($cell_from->getValue());
    }
}
```